# How to call clearTimeout and still run the setTimeout's function?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
let delayTimeout = null;
const delayExecution = mls => {
    console.log('Delaying for', mls);
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        delayTimeout = setTimeout(() => resolve('ok'), mls);
    })
}

const main = async () => {
    axios.post('URL', {data})
             .then(response => {
                 if(response passes some condition){
                     clearTimeout(delayTimeout);
                 }
             })

   const res = await delayExecution(30000)
   console.log("DONE!")
}

main();
```

After the axios call, I may want to terminate the `delayExecution` by clearing the timeout inside it. How do I clearTimeout inside my `delayExecution` function but still resolve the Promise?

In essence, I'm trying to finish `delayExecution` before its time, but still resolve the promise inside it.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do. If you don't want to clear the timeout - because you want the function to still execute after 10 seconds regardless - then simply don't call `clearTimeout`.

Comment: Depending on the `/* Seome logic here */` I may want the function to execute before the 10 seconds.

Comment: So you want to conditionally change the duration of the timeout? Then why not just set a variable, say `duration`, according to whatever logic you need, then just do `setTimeout(doneFunc, duration)` at the end? (It's possible I'm still not understanding your requirements however.)

Comment: It's not that I want to conditionally change the duration of the timeout, but rather under some conditions, I want the `setTimeout` function to finish early, in which case I still want the `doneFunc` function to run.

Comment: your setTimeOut function is precisely made to execute your `doneFunc` function after a delay. if you want it to run before do not use setTimeOut

Comment: *I still want the doneFunc function to run* - but *when* do you want it to run? If it's still after an interval, just a different one, you can do as I said in my previous comment. If you want it to run straight away in that case, simply call it directly (`doneFunc()`) at the point you clear the timeout.

Comment: Excellent point. The problem of course is the `doneFunc` is not that easy to run. The code I provided is very simplistic for brevity. In production, my setTimeout function actually fires a resolve to a Promise and I'm not sure how to call it directly like that. Indeed, I should have done a better job explaining my requirements. So let me tweak the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your edit, I'll just leave another response. Note that I haven't tested it, my mind is currently focused on my code I'm writing alongside this hehe

```
let delayTimeout = null;
let resolveHandler = null;
const delayExecution = mls => {
    console.log('Delaying for', mls);
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        resolveHandler = resolve;
        delayTimeout = setTimeout(() => resolve('ok'), mls);
    })
}

const main = async () => {
    axios.post('URL', {data})
             .then(response => {
                 if(response passes some condition){
                     resolveHandler('ok');
                     clearTimeout(delayTimeout);
                 }
             })

   const res = await delayExecution(30000)
   console.log("DONE!")
}

main();
```

The idea is just to assign the resolve function to another auxiliary variable which you can then use elsewhere :)

Comment: Yessir!! Works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help, bud :) Add me on linkedin, we can keep in touch

Answer (score 1):

doneFunc should have the clearTimeout within it, so after the function is complete the timeout is cleared.

Also, for the first setTimeout parameter, you can just pass the name of the function.

Actually for timeout, you don't need the clearTimeout since it will only be ran ONCE compared to interval which is continuing run.

```js
const doneFunc = () => {console.log('Finished job');clearTimeout(f);}

const f = setTimeout(doneFunc, 100);
```

Comment: I get that it will only run once, but under certain conditions I want that one run to finish early, in which case I want the `doneFunc` to still fire.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the function independently from the timeout, just declare the function outside of it, then call it whenever you want. You have most of the code done

```
const doneFunc = () => console.log('Finished job');

const f = setTimeout(() => doneFunc(), 10000);

/* Seome logic here */

if (condition to run before timeout) {
  clearTimeout(f);
 doneFunc();

}

/* end of logic */
```

Comment: This looks like the solution here. With the possible removal of the final clearTimeout.

Comment: This is an excellent point. The problem of course is the doneFunc is not that easy to run directly. The code I provided is very simplistic for brevity. In production, my setTimeout function actually fires a resolve to a Promise and I'm not sure how to call it directly like that. I should have done a better job explaining my requirements. So I'm going to tweak the question a little.

Answer (score 1):

I have imagined that :

```js
const runOnDelay = function( fct, delay )
        {
        let obj    = {}
          , isDone = false
          , refTim = setTimeout(()=>
              {
              isDone = true
              fct()
              }, delay)
          ;
        obj.stop = () =>
          { 
          clearTimeout(refTim)
          if (!isDone)
            fct()
          isDone = true
          }
        return obj
        }
```

## **usage:**

```js
const doneFunc = () => console.log('Finished job')

let myBoy = runOnDelay(doneFunc, 1000)

 //...

myBoy.stop()
```

Comment: This is actually a really neat piece of code. Too much work for me to rewrite my current logic around it, but I will no doubt it use elsewhere in my app.